# soundcloud api tracks 403 response

Tags: api, soundcloud, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to connect soundcloud api. I'm connecting player with track at user page by track link. And I have problem with some tracks (403 response code on request). For example:

**connects fine:**
https://soundcloud.com/artemiev/ditcvbecfh0m

**returns 403 response code:**
https://soundcloud.com/artemiev/w82hggokbh09

Please, help me find some solution. Thanks

Comment: I get on both 200? Maybe a Caching Problem?

Comment: This question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360202/soundcloud-api-urls-timing-out-and-then-returning-error-403-on-about-50-of-trac# TL;RD SoundCloud API return 403 if they think that the track should not be available via API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SoundCloud API URLs timing out and then returning error 403 on about 50% of tracks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360202/soundcloud-api-urls-timing-out-and-then-returning-error-403-on-about-50-of-trac)