# SoundCloud API URLs timing out and then returning error 403 on about 50% of tracks

Tags: soundcloud

I noticed this issue has been reported in the past a lot, but it appears no one of the SoundCloud support team actually has been able to address the issue.

Ever since this week, SoundCloud API URLs are timing out followed by a 403 error when requested again.

For example, the following URL will return an empty page, and then a 403 error when refreshed:
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/256202279?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]

This URL does work:
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/256299992.json?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]

*Update:* As of 5/25/2016, the issue is still not fixed and SoundCloud has yet to reply with a satisfactory response.

Comment: It appears almost every new track is returning this error. I received one reply saying they don't know what's going on, and that they don't have an active API team. So much funding yet no active API team.

Comment: I received another email saying SoundCloud users are configuring their tracks to restrict API permissions. This is not true. With all permissions enabled the timetout into 403 error is still being returned.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. All permissions are enabled on the tracks. Any help from Soundcloud??

Comment: I wouldn't count on it. This issue has been ignored for over 6 months.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***Update***: As of 5/25/2016, the issue is still not fixed and SoundCloud has yet to reply with a satisfactory response. They're saying that right holders have the option to disable API requests, but every time I ask if they can show me a screenshot or anything at all that proves this behavior is intentional, their helpdesk no longer replies.

SoundCloud emailed back saying they have introduced an option for right holders to disable all API access to tracks by default, returning this 403 error when requested. They also said it's understandable that this is a confusing feature, and that they hope to make it more clear.

SoundCloud: please let applications read basic track information. Blocking access from simple information such as track ID breaks so many applications that use your API. It doesn't make any sense to block access to applications from retrieving a simple ID, title, or duration.

Also, most users who have tracks that are blocking API access have no idea about configuring this, so I'm still fairly convinced this is a bug in the SoundCloud API.

Comment: Did you get any further answer than this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It appears that all SoundCloud uploads licensed by major publishers have all API data revoked.

Comment: Just tweeted at SoundCloud Dev about this....it's crazy they would cripple their API like this. I'm debating pulling their API integration out of my app entirely.

Comment: I agree, it is a bug. 
If it is an option, why is it possible to get this info with the widget api?

Answer (score 0):

I think about a quota, or a kind of blacklist...
Because I had this error from one server, and when I tried from another (to change IP), the request si OK...

Answer (score 0):

**Not the perfect solution, just a workaround...**

Using the client side [SoundCloud Widget API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#methods) you'll be able to load the track in iframe, then get info with getCurrentSound method.

```
//javascript code sample...
var widget= SC.Widget(iframe);
widget.getCurrentSound(
 function(infos){
    console.log(infos);
 }
);
```

Testing on https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html with https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/256202279 (and many others unresolved API urls) it works.

Not the perfect solution, I know...