# Receiving Empty List from Soundcould while trying to integrate the tracks

Tags: api, soundcloud

While integrating with Soundcloud I receive the following empty list  http://prnt.sc/b4p653
soundcould user has tracks . 
What can be the reason of such failure?

Answer (score 0):

For example that the track owner has blocked API access to the track. See for example: [SoundCloud API URLs timing out and then returning error 403 on about 50% of tracks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360202/soundcloud-api-urls-timing-out-and-then-returning-error-403-on-about-50-of-trac/36529330#36529330)

> SoundCloud emailed back saying they have introduced an option for right holders to disable all API access to tracks by default, returning this 403 error when requested. They also said it's understandable that this is a confusing feature, and that they hope to make it more clear.

You get the 403 on the specific track(s), the list of tracks is empty if all tracks give this error.