# Can't get tracks via SoundCloud API

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I am trying to get array of tracks from soundcloud via Javascript Sdk, here is some code:

```
SC.initialize({
            client_id: my_id
        });

SC.get('/tracks', 
        {
            q: 'ellie', limit: 10 // ellie is my query string
        }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);   // get array of 2 tracks   
});
```

The problem is that I get array of two tracks. But the same request on 
[soundcloud](http://soundcloud.com) gives me over 500+ tracks. Why? Am I doing something wrong??

**UPDATE:**

I've found out that if I change limit property I'll get more tracks, but not equal to limit value. For example if `limit === 20` I get 7 tracks, and if `limit === 30` I get 12 tracks.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to try with different client_id

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
       SC.initialize({
            client_id: '02gUJC0hH2ct1EGOcYXQIzRFU91c72Ea'
       });

       SC.get('/tracks', 
       {
            q: 'ellie', limit: 10 // ellie is my query string
       }, 
       function(response) {
       console.log(response);   // get array of 2 tracks   
});
</script>
```

**Response** http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=31d4b86e517c4d46b92c1d3bbcdc5f77

Comment: I see it works! But what's wrong with my client_id=cf3f997475d773c4b2db2ac4166ae36f ???

Comment: @SergeyTyupaev May be due to Soundcloud Rate Limit againts  client_id https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/rate-limits

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so. It's test app and I barely had 200 request. And the limit is 15 thousands :)

Comment: @SergeyTyupaev it will be more userful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360202/soundcloud-api-urls-timing-out-and-then-returning-error-403-on-about-50-of-trac

Comment: thanks for the link! Now I see that it's soundcloud problem. But I have one more question for you :) There is a link in that post, which doesn't [work](https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/256202279?client_id=aec6dfcf7796beb6bfff11206aae491b) with my client_id. But If I put your client_id, it'll [work](https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/256202279?client_id=02gUJC0hH2ct1EGOcYXQIzRFU91c72Ea). Why your client_id is so magic?

Comment: @SergeyTyupaev As per your client_id is return wih 403 error code and its also define in above link

Comment: @SergeyTyupaev 403 Forbidden that means 
"You don't have access to whatever it is you're asking for." thats you need to change client_id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113613/discussion-between-sergey-tyupaev-and-ashish-chaturvedi).