# Soundcloud API Returning 403 on Some Tracks

Tags: json, soundcloud

I'm developing a site using the soundcloud API but it is giving me some troubles.

For some odd reason some tracks are returning a 403 forbidden error, whilst others are not. Does anybody know the cause of this issue?

For example, this works perfectly:
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/334511096.json?client_id=REDACTED_CLIENT_ID

Whilst this gives the 403 forbidden error:
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/328406416.json?client_id=REDACTED_CLIENT_ID

Any suggestions would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the track owner has made the track private so it's only shared through a secret link that the track owner can give out.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered here: [SoundCloud API URLs timing out and then returning error 403 on about 50% of tracks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360202/soundcloud-api-urls-timing-out-and-then-returning-error-403-on-about-50-of-trac#)

TL;RD SoundCloud API return 403 if they think that the track should not be available via API.